# Как сохранить в глобальную переменную строку из БД?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse.com

В БД Parse у меня есть таблица `Gtree`, где одному пользователю соответствует одно `String` значение (`content`). Как текущему пользователю изъять значение этой строки и сохранить как глобальную переменную?

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var Gtree = Parse.Object.extend("Gtree");
var output = "";

function loadTree() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Gtree);
    query.include("user");
    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i in results) {
                var content = results[i].get("content");
                var user = results[i].get("user");
                var username = user.get("username");
                var id = results[i].id;
                output = content;
                console.log("CONTENT:" + content);
                return content;
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error:" + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема с `output = content;`? Так как у вас всё равно далее в цикле идёт `return content;` (который и возвращает результат "в никуда", и делает `for` бессмысленной затеей), то в `output` окажется `content` для первой строки результатов.

Comment: я хочу сохранить значение gtree.content в переменную output. не силен в js

Comment: Фраза _не силен в js_ не является волшебной, ничего толком не объясняет и не решает. По поводу _`content` в `output`_ - так вы это и делаете в строке `output = content;`. Ещё раз: в чем проблема возникает?

Comment: так не сохраняется в output. где я ошибся?

Comment: Как вы проверяется, что не сохранилось в `output`?

Comment: loadTree();
console.log("output:"+output);

Comment: Вот мы и подошли к реальной проблеме. Дело в том, что `.find()` выполняется асинхронно, поэтому сразу после вызова функции в консоли вы ничего не увидите, так как функция их `success` к этому моменту ещё даже не будет вызвана. Про то как обращаться с асинхронным кодом в Интернете есть много статей.

Comment: как переписать код чтобы значение сохранялось?

Comment: У меня создаётся впечатление, что вы меня не слушаете. Ещё раз: значение **сохраняется** в переменной `output`, но вы пытаетесь его считать **слишком рано**.

Answer (score 1):

Размещу вариант решения проблемы с кодом с использованием [jQuery.Deferred()](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Также `for` был заменён на `if`, так как, насколько я понял, нужна лишь первая строка результатов:

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var Gtree = Parse.Object.extend("Gtree");

function loadTree() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Gtree);
    query.include("user");
    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                var result = results[0];
                var content = result.get("content");
                var user = result.get("user");
                var username = user.get("username");
                var id = result.id;
                console.log("CONTENT:" + content);
                deferred.resolve(content);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error:" + error.message);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

var promise = loadTree();
promise.done(function(output) {
    console.log("output:" + output);
});
```

Код протестирован лишь на отсутствие синтаксических ошибок, но идею демонстрирует. В Parse существует своя реализация `Promise` (обещаний), но это нужно изучать [документацию](https://parse.com/docs/ru/js/guide).

Comment: Зачем вы так любите `deferred`? Можно же использовать метод `then` - и просто вернуть из колбека `content`, а результат вызова `then` вернуть из функции!

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что `Promise` является хорошей альтернативой передачи `callback`-функции (для вызова её по окончании работы асинхронного кода). Почему я использую `jQuery.Deferred()`, а не `Promise` из Parse - я объяснил в ответе. Использование `.then()` внутри `loadTree`, в конечном счете, не упростит вызов и использование функции `loadTree`.

Comment: Нет, *такое* провернуть нельзя - надо использовать метод `then`, а не коллбек `success`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, нашел такое в документации. Если я правильно понял по беглому просмотру, то всё сводится к чему-то вроде этого: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dvd6ptz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос также есть в [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431184/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Как уже указали в коментариях в parse есть функция then, которая в официальной документации практически не описана, хотя примеры с ней повсюду. Можно [тут](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) почитатать напрмер.

Я бы использовал что-то вроде следующего кода:

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var Gtree = Parse.Object.extend("Gtree");
var output = "";

function loadTree() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Gtree);
    query.include("user");
    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {

        if (results.length > 0) {
            var result = results[0];
            var content = result.get("content");
            var user = result.get("user");
            var username = user.get("username");
            var id = result.id;

            output = content;

        }

    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Query Error:" + error.message);
    }

   }).then(function (results) {
       //переменная results должна быть, по идее, из предыдущей функции.
       //Cюда мы попадем после того как отработает асинхронная функия find
       //В этой функции мы продолжаем работать с output
       console.log("output:" + output);

   });
}
```

Comment: В комментариях к моему ответу мы пришли к [этой версии](http://jsfiddle.net/9dvd6ptz/1/) (не знаю уж правильно ли она работает). Идея вопроса и моего ответа состоит в том, чтобы воспользоваться значением `output` вне функции. В вашем же случае `console.log(output);` сразу после `loadTree();` будет выдавать пустую строку. `.then()` выполняется тоже асинхронно.

Comment: @Regent, абсолютно согласен вызов console.log(output); сразу после loadTree(); будет выдавать пустую строку. Просто хотел привести пример другого синтаксиса в стиле parse.

Comment: А какие-нибудь мысли по предоставленному мною fiddle у вас есть? Так как я до этого никогда не работал с Parse и не тестировал код из fiddle, то включать его в ответ (чтобы в ответt было решение без jQuery) хочется только при наличия уверенности, что этот код работает.