# Присвоение значения глобальной переменной

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Как присвоить переменной `LastChatId` значение внутри функции, выполняемой в `success`? `console.log(LastChatId);` выдаёт `0` вместо `100`.

Пример моего кода:

```
var LastChatId = 0;

//Ajax запрос к облачному сервису
//Узнать уникальный Id для нового чата и увелить на +1
Parse.Cloud.run('GetLastChatIdAndIncement', {}, {
    success: function (result) {
        //функция выполняется нормально и мы попадаем сюда. проверено
        LastChatId = 100;
        // но присваивание не работает LastChatId остается =0
    },
    error: function (object, error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});

console.log(LastChatId); // дает 0
response.success(LastChatId); // дает 0
```

Comment: В `LastChatId` **присваивается** значение `100` прямо в этой строке: `LastChatId = 100;`.

Comment: И то, что `console.log(LastChatId);` выдаёт `0`, - тоже верно. Попросту потому, что `console.log(LastChatId);` отрабатывает **раньше** `LastChatId = 100;`.

Comment: @TheDoctor а почему метка _parse.com_ была убрана?

Comment: @Regent: рискну предположить: потому, что parse.com не имеет к сути вопроса никакого отношения?

Comment: @Regent точно! Конвертируйте коментарий в ответ :)

Comment: @VladD я в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431151/Как-сохранить-в-глобальную-переменную-строку-из-БД) тоже пытался автору втолковать, что его код выполняется асинхронно. И там тоже использовался `Parse`. Чтобы понять о чем речь, я разыскал эту библиотеку в Интернете: на [parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/ru/js/guide) она и есть. Просто метки `Parse` нет.

Comment: @koks_rs сейчас оформлю.

Comment: Потому что многоуважаемый @VladD правильно заметил - кроме рекламной деятельности, эта метка ничего не делает.

Comment: @TheDoctor так ведь метка _parse.com_, по сути, аналогична, например, _jquery_. Ведь имеет смысл указывать в метках используемую библиотеку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parse.Cloud.run()` выполняется асинхронно, поэтому `console.log(LastChatId);` выполняется до присвоения `LastChatId` (`LastChatId = 100;`).

Решением проблемы, например, являются:

- использование `LastChatId` только внутри безымянной функции, вызываемой при `success` (если код достаточно короткий).
- вынесение функции, выполняемой при `success`, в отдельный блок кода.

  ```
  function onSuccess(result)
  {
      var LastChatId = 100;
      ...
  }
  ```

  и в `.run()`:

  ```
  success: onSuccess
  ```
- использование `Promise` (обещания). `Promise`, насколько я видел, реализован в самой *Parse*, но можно использовать и [jQuery.Deferred()](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) для этого.

  Пример:

  ```
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() { deferred.resolve(100); }, 5000);
  var promise = deferred.promise();
  promise.done(function(LastChatId)
  {
      console.log(LastChatId);
  });
  ```

  [Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9k30nfxg/).

Comment: а есть способ cделать код синхронным? Ну что-то вроде await в шарпе? чтобы код ждал выполнения в определенной точке? 
Или размещать дальнейший код в функции в success это считается нормальной практикой?

Comment: @koks_rs: Если быть точным, `await` **не** делает код на шарпе синхронным. Он просто позволяет использовать для асинхронного кода такой же синтаксис, как и для синхронного.

Comment: @koks_rs, нет, к сожалению, javascript по многим параметрам отстает от серьезных языков. Использование цепочек promise позволяет привести код ближе всего к желаемому виду.

Comment: @koks_rs дописал ответ.

Comment: в es7 обещается await, так что, по крайней мере на сервер-сайде, можно будет пользовать достаточно скоро